# Can't connect DB with Teradata express studio

Tags: jdbc, odbc, teradata

I have installed Teradata in my VM, and can connect the dbc database with the in-built Terraform studio express .

Now, I want to connect the dbc database with the Terraform studio express outside my VM i.e. in Windows. But when I try to test the connection using the same login details, it shows me "**Ping Failed**".

The detailed error message is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 17.10.00.14] [Error 1277] [SQLState 08S01] Login timeout for Connection to 192.168.XXX.XX Mon Jan 10 19:39:51 IST 2022 socket orig=192.168.XXX.XX cid=50e21bd3 sess=0 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)   at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$ConnectThread.run(TDNetworkIOIF.java:1543)  
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:95)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:70)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeIoJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:208)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorAnalyzer.analyzeIoError(ErrorAnalyzer.java:59)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.createSocketConnection(TDNetworkIOIF.java:188)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.createIO(TDNetworkIOIF.java:174)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeradataConnection.<init>(GenericTeradataConnection.java:290)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:186)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6ConnectionFactory.java:25)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:181)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:171)
at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.doConnect(TeraDriver.java:230)
at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.connect(TeraDriver.java:163)
at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataJDBCConnection.makeConnection(TeradataJDBCConnection.java:286)
at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataJDBCConnection.createConnection(TeradataJDBCConnection.java:124)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataPingFactory.createConnection(TeradataPingFactory.java:36)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$ConnectThread.run(TDNetworkIOIF.java:1543)
```

Please provide any solutions to fix this.

**Note:** I have also installed the Teradata tools and utilities suite (ODBC driver, BTEQ, etc)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Teradata. You have to configure your VM to allow connections from outside that network. How that works depends on what tool you are using.

Comment: Is the network adapter set to "bridged"? If so, is the IP address you are using to attempt the connection the same as the address you see with "ip addr show dev eth0" from the VM command line?